# Push a video to Windows Media Services 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-media-encoder, windows-media-server, windows-media-services

I have a Windows Media Services 2008 Server (NOT IIS Smooth Streaming) and I need to push a video to publishing point. 
What is the C# code (VS2010) to get this? What SDK I need to install? Where is the docs?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Riccardo - Have you made any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

WMS API is language-independent, so you can use your language of choice. Most of the sample code will be in C++. You need to do the translation.